# Mysql query to copy new data from one DB to another

Tags: database, mysql

I have a situation. While we upgraded our server drives, we took a backup of our DB and then imported it again and then site was live, its after a weeks we realize that import did not copy entire backup from dump file as when we checked it was only 13 GB which it suppose to be 60 GB. The interesting thing is, there is one big table which we figured out is copied in a funny way, it is huge and its just copied few initial records, say like 2000-5000 and it copied last records say 400000-500000 and there is no records in between. Isn't that weird? cause while we imported we checked initial and last entries and thought it copied everything. Then we created a new DB and imported a dump again and now it seems to be ok, but we have the new entry already in our live DB(13GB data), so we have to copy those and add to our newl imported DB. What will be the idle way to copy those new records in to recovered DB? I mean some query which will search the new DB and add only new records found. So do I have to take dump of our 13 GB and then import? Or is there anyways to copy from live DB?

Comment: I will make it more simpler now, I want to copy data from one DB to another DB . I want to overwrite if any row of record is different and add the new records if found, I dont want to delete the existing record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqldump with the following option: `--insert-ignore` - writes INSERT IGNORE statements rather than INSERT statements (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore)
With IGNORE keyword, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table is not inserted and no duplicate-key error is issued.